# how to count each characters in a string and display each instance in a table format

Tags: sql, string, count

my table master_schedule

```
cable_no
D110772
D110773
D110774
D110775
D110776
D110777
D110778
D110779
D110880
```

I would like to create a loop so that each character in the string counted and displayed

```
D 9
1 18
2 1
3 1
AND SO ON .......
```

how can i modify in these sql query mentioned below:

```
select (sum(LEN(cable_no) - LEN(REPLACE(cable_no, 'D', '')))*2) as FERRUL_qtyx2
from MASTER_schedule
```

Answer (score 1):

Something like this:

```
select substring(cable_no, n.n, 1) as letter, count(*) as cnt
from FERRUL_qtyx2 t cross join
     (select 1 as n union all select 2 union all select 3 union all select 4 union all
      select 5 union all select 6 union all select 7
     ) n
group by substring(cable_no, n.n, 1);
```

This creates a sequence of numbers `n` up to the length of the string.  It then uses `cross join` and `substring()` to extract the nth character of each `cable_no`.

In general, this will be faster than doing a `union all` seven times.  The `union all` approach will typically scan the table 7 times.  This will scan the table only once.

Comment: +1, tested my and yours solution, yours actually faster. Added another one without hardcoded numbers (I know about spt_values, just don't like it).

Answer (score 0):

you can use [recursive common table expression](http://technet.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms186243%28v=sql.105%29.aspx):

```
with cte(symbol, cable_no) as (
    select
        left(cable_no, 1), right(cable_no, len(cable_no) - 1)
    from Table1

    union all

    select
        left(cable_no, 1), right(cable_no, len(cable_no) - 1)
    from cte
    where cable_no <> ''
)
select symbol, count(*)
from cte
group by symbol
```

[**=> sql fiddle demo**](http://sqlfiddle.com/#!3/445c2/4)

Another approach (made after Gordon Linoff solution):

```
;with cte(n) as (
    select 1
    union all
    select n + 1 from cte where n < 7
)
select substring(t.cable_no, n.n, 1) as letter, count(*) as cnt
from #Table1 as t
    cross join cte as n
group by substring(t.cable_no, n.n, 1);
```

[**=> sql fiddle demo**](http://sqlfiddle.com/#!3/445c2/5)